# Control audio volume with a range from 0 to 99

Tags: java, android, audio, android-emulator, audio-streaming

I need to increase progressively the volume of a sound while the sound is playing.
What I found till now, is to use the **setStreamVolume()** method of the **AudioManager** class. This works great but it allows me to specify the volume from 0 to 9 range. However, I want to increase the volume by smaller units, from 0 - 99.

Is there a way to accomplish this task?

Comment: I would use `getStreamMaxVolume`. If it really returns 10 (I didn't check), then I guess there is no easy solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to do this with [AudioTrack](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioTrack.html#setStereoVolume%28float,%20float%29)